# How to prove the following statement regarding the successor function and addition of natural numbers?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-writing, induction, recursion, peano-axioms

Natural numbers (including 0) and the successor function are defined as per the Peano Axioms (you can check them on wikipedia). Addition is defined recursively as follows:

$a+0=a$

$a+S(b)=S(a)+b$

With these definitions in mind, I need to prove that $a+S(b)=S(a+b)$

I tried using induction on b, and while proving the base case was trivial, I only end up with a circular argument when I try to prove the inductive step.

Comment: You should prove $\forall a (a + S(b) = S(a + b))$ by induction on $b$.

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA I intenionally used a different (hopefully equivalent, though I have yet it prove this) definition for addition, which is why I am trying to prove all of additions's properties from scratch, i.e. I am not allowed to use any "preliminary lemmas" and similar things. At the end of your proof, you state that $Sb+Sa=S(Sb+a)$... Which is exactly what I am trying to prove, so I can't use this statement in the proof. Also, I am not allowes to consider addition commutative yet either.

Comment: You should probably show your failed attempt. It might turn out to be correct, and anyway we can better see where exactly your confusion is.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: try to prove the stronger claim:
$$
\forall x(a + S(x) = S(a+x))
$$

Comment: This is exactly what I am trying to prove, essentially that $\forall a\forall b(a+S(b)=S(a+b))$

Comment: No it isn't. You don't have the $\forall$, which is vital as you need to apply the inductive hypothesis with $S(b)$ in place of $b$.. @MauroALLEGRANZA leaves this implicit in his answer, but that is a sleight of hand.